# Iterate through appended json file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have this code:

```
function heatMapRange() {
  var script1 = document.createElement('script');
  script1.src = 'allCoords.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script1);
}
```

which appends the allCoords.js file above:

```
allCoords_callback({
  "coordinates": [
    [50.1729677, 12.6692243, 580000],
    [50.001168, 14.4270033, 2895000],
    [50.6988037, 13.9384015, 945000],
    [50.1218161, 14.4824004, 409900],
    [49.470061, 17.0937597, 1499000],
    [49.8509959, 18.5593087, 380000]
  ]
});
```

What I want is to iterate through this data with something like this:

```
function allCoords_callback(results1) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results1.coordinates.length; i++) {
    alert(results1.coordinates[i]);
  }
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate an array in javascript with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap).

In your example will be something like:

```
results1.coordinates.map(function(coordinate) { alert(coordinate); })
```

That's about iterating part.

Then, another topic is how do you get JSON you need to process. In the example given on [Google Maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/earthquakes) they do it using [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) just because that is the way the [real-time earthquake data works](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/). Another method to fetch data are [XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (AKA as AJAX). This is a more common practice and I would recomend using it if possible.

In your case I would re-write your code to look something like this:

```
function heatMapRange(){
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', '/allCoords.js', true);
  request.onload = function () {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      // Success!
      var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      // process the data in the response, like
      // iterating through the list of coordinates
      data.coordinates.map(function(coordinate) { alert(coordinate); })
    } else {
      // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
    }
  }
  request.error = function () {
    // There was a connection error of some sort
  }
  request.send();
}
```

Which fetch the data from the JSON file `allCoords.json`:

```
{
    "coordinates": [
        [50.1729677,12.6692243,580000],
        [50.001168,14.4270033,2895000],
        [50.6988037,13.9384015,945000],
        [50.1218161,14.4824004,409900],
        [49.470061,17.0937597,1499000],
        [49.8509959,18.5593087,380000]
    ]
}
```

This way of fetching data from a server align more with the best practices used in the industry. This is just the straight forward example using vanillaJS XMLHttpRequest. There are tons of libraries that simplify this action. Even better there is [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) coming tackling the topic of fetching resources.

Comment: So I should put this line in to the allCoords_callback? Because the callback never runs anyway

Comment: Ok, that is another question. I don't fully get why are you getting the coordinates object by appending a script instead of using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (AKA as AJAX).
Can you give a bit of context on why you do that?

Comment: I am using google maps API to create heatmaps using this example : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/earthquakes I was able to create heat map. My problem is that I need to add another child with json data to make another heatmap layer. I am doing the same thing as in this example but the callback never runs.

Comment: Try to rename your ```allCords_callback``` founction to ```eqfeed_callback``` and tell me what happens

Comment: But I have one eqfeed_callback already that contains another data. Anyway I did it and the alert still wont show up

Comment: @nocturne, I have update the answer to cover the fetching data part of your question too, not just the iterating part. Please, let me know if this make sense to you.

Comment: I appreciate your work, my script worked fine I had have just disabled the pop ups in chrome. I am sure your script will work too so I will mark your answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well the code on the top works, problem was that I disabled the alerts in google chrome. So closing the tab and reopening page did the trick.